# Mongoose Versioning Issue: How to handle rapid fire requests (e.g. removing a bunch of items from array within a document)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In specific scenarios when our users remove a bunch of tags from a document, we get a bunch of VersionErrors from Mongoose and the actions are obviously not all fulfilled. Just trying to figure out how to get around this / make sure it doesn't happen. Open to architectural changes in the data structure!

Here's the scenario:

We have a model called Ask:

```
var AskSchema = new Schema({
...
    _tags: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag'}],
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true}
}
```

On our interface, we display the list of Tag models that are associated with the specific Ask the user is looking at and they can add new tags or remove existing ones.

If the user removes let's say 4-5 tags at the same time, we send 4-5 separate HTTP DELETE requests to our server and each request tries to remove that ID from the `_tags` array.

This is where the VersionError occurs, which is exactly what Mongooses' version control system is supposed to do.

The question is: what should I be doing from the front-end side or the backend side to avoid this. My current thoughts are:

1. Queuing up the requests on the front-end side (a bit annoying, but possible).
2. Create a "relationship" model called AskTag that just holds `_ask` and `_tag` in order to maintain these relationships (smells very SQLy)
3. Re-fetch the document when VersionErrors happen and just apply the `ask._tags.pull(tagId)` again

Am I missing any solutions? What's the best practice here?

Comment: What are you passing as input to HTTP Delete request?

Comment: It's a REST endpoint. No body, just straight DELETE to /<path-to-api>/asks/<ask_id>/tags/<tag_id>